# How to grep "find -print0" output?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find, xargs

I tried this:

```
find /usr/lib -print0 | grep zip | xargs -0 -I{} echo "found file: {}"
find /usr/lib -print0 | grep --null zip | xargs -0 -I{} echo "found file: {}"
```

But it doesn't work because grep only says there is a binary file matching.
I want grep to output null terminated lines.

Is it possible to fix this without changing the whole command? I know it's possible to use `find -name ... -exec ...`. But it would be nice if my existing command could be fixed instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you tried `fdfind`, I find it much easier to use... excuse the pun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the use of `--null`, I’m assuming you’re using GNU `grep`. You can tell it to consider the *data* as null-separated [with the `-z` (`--null-data`) option](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Other-Options.html#index-_002dz), and to treat everything as text with the `-a` option:

```
find /usr/lib -print0 |
  grep -a -z zip |
  xargs -r0 printf 'found file: %s\n'
```

(remember you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data).

[`--null` only affect’s `grep`’s output of file names](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Output-Line-Prefix-Control.html#index-_002dZ), and has no effect here.

As you mention, you can do this entirely using GNU `find`, without even using `-exec`, though you need `LC_ALL=C` to be able to find files whose path has non-text on either side of `zip` (unlikely in `/usr/lib` though):

```
LC_ALL=C find /usr/lib -path '*zip*' -printf 'found file: %p\n'
```

Comment: Your command works even using echo as shown in my original command. Does this mean I can stick to echo or should I switch to printf?

Comment: [This answer explains why `echo` should be avoided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/86440) in this kind of scenario.

Comment: I expect the OP is using `-print0` to accommodate file names that contain newlines (otherwise why do it?) and so YMMV using `printf 'found file: %s\n'` instead of `printf 'found file: %s\0'` (and ditto for `-printf 'found file: %p\n'`)